# faster way to find if a string contains any value of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I like to find the fastest way (other than looping every element of the array) to find if a `$string ='hello my name is john'` contains any of the words on a `$array = ['none','tomatos','john']` and in this case does not contain any of the black listed words `$black_array = ['find','other']`

in this example the result should be True.

Currently i loop every element of the array and use `$string.search($array[i])`

Comment: _"in this example..."_ what example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to implement this would be to create regex's out of each array and test for a match in the whitelist and no match in the blacklist:

```js
const $string = 'hello my name is john';
const $array = ['none', 'tomatos', 'john'];
const $black_array = ['find', 'other']

const white = new RegExp('\\b(' + $array.join('|') + ')\\b');
const black = new RegExp('\\b(' + $black_array.join('|') + ')\\b');

const match = white.test($string) && !black.test($string);

console.log(match);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, I compared operation times using `performance.now()` markers. Your answer is significantly faster than mine (0.085ms vs 0.15ms) 

Comment: @Phil interesting. Perhaps because the `.some` and `.every` functions in your code are effectively taking place inside the regex engine, where they can possibly be more compiled?

Comment: I figured it was really just down to 2 explicit `RegExp` constructions and tests vs up to `allowed.length + banned.length` constructions and tests. At its shortest run, mine still does the same amount of work as yours does for every run (excluding individual regex testing time)

Comment: @Phil that's basically what I was saying... it would be interesting to know how much work goes into a `RegExp` construct, my suspicion is that it isn't actually a lot.

Comment: I'd say it's more the repeated tests. Tokenising and indexing the string up front would be the optimal way to go which is what a real search engine would do

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use a combination of `Array.prototype.some()` for the allowed words and a negated `Array.prototype.every()` for the banned ones.

```js
const wordToRegex = word => new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`, "i")

const check = (str, allowed = [], banned = []) =>
  allowed.some(word => wordToRegex(word).test(str))
    && banned.every(word => !wordToRegex(word).test(str))
  
const allowed = ['none','tomatos','john']
const banned = ['find','other']

console.info(check('hello my name is john', allowed, banned))
console.info(check('hello my other name is john', allowed, banned))
```

Not sure I'd call this *fast* though. You'd be better off with an actual indexing search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Other response are adequate for relatively small array sizes. But if you want to optimize this for the case, say, where you have millions of candidate substrings in your array (which is generally the impetus for optimization), I would suggest constructing a "string tree."

In this tree, the root branches to each candidate first byte. So, for example if the array contained only `{"none", "tomatoes", "john"}`, there would be three child nodes from the root: `'n', 't', and 'j'`. (Multiple candidate strings starting with the first byte would descend through the same tree node.) Then those nodes in turn branch to candidate second bytes. And so on.

This approach allows you to make a small number of comparisons for each byte in your string: always less than 255, but generally much much fewer. In comparison, if you have a million candidate strings, using the other proposed approaches (including the accepted one), in the worst case (which again is the case we generally optimize against) you will have to make millions of comparisons for each string byte.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.join()` and `RegExp()`. For example:

```js
let $string ='hello my name is john';
let $black_string ='hello my name is other';
let $black_string2 ='hello my name is mother';
let $array = ['none','tomatos','john'];
let $black_array = ['find','other'];

let re = new RegExp("\\b"+$array.join("\\b|\\b")+"\\b");
let re_blck = new RegExp("\\b"+$black_array.join("\\b|\\b")+"\\b");
let $hasArray = re.test($string);
let $hasBlackArray = re_blck.test($string);
console.log($hasArray,$hasBlackArray);
$hasArray = re.test($black_string);
$hasBlackArray = re_blck.test($black_string);
console.log($hasArray,$hasBlackArray);
$hasArray = re.test($black_string2);
$hasBlackArray = re_blck.test($black_string2);
console.log($hasArray,$hasBlackArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using multiple condition check

```js
const array = ["none", "tomatos", "john"]
const black_array = ["find", "other"]
const check = (str) =>
  [
    array.some((word) => str.includes(word)),
    black_array.every((word) => !str.includes(word)),
  ].every((criteria) => criteria === true)

console.log(check("hello my name is john"))
console.log(check("hello my name is other"))
console.log(check("hello my name is peter"))
```

Comment: This suffers the same problem as Peter's answer. Without word-boundaries, you run into false positives